# To click on a button using text in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

Hi Below is my code,

```
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" id=oldcontent>40_FDI12p_</TD>
<TD>..........</TD>
<TD>..........</TD>
<TD>
    <form action="get.do"  method="post"  style="margin:3px">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Edit"  />
    </form> 
</TD>   
</TR>
```

I need to click on the Edit button based on the text present in the first 40_FDI12p_.Can anyone help me with the xpath?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"//td[contains(text(),'40_FDI12p_')]"
```

will serve the purpose.

Comment: what is selenium here?

Answer (score 0):

I do this (c#):

```
public static void ClickButton(this ISearchContext searchContext, string text)
{
    searchContext.TagNames("button").First(x => x.Text == text).Click();
}
```

With

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> TagNames(this ISearchContext searchContext, string tagName)
{
    return searchContext.FindElements(By.TagName(tagName));
}
```